# If-construct advice needed

Tags: c++, c, loops, modulus

I have a for loop in which I placed several if statements. The objective of these conditionals is to check divisibility of a number and then output a string if the number is divisible by 3. If the number is divisible by 5, another string will be outputted. However, if the number is divisible by both 3 and 5, an entirely different string will be outputted in its place instead of the other strings.

Here is my code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= file_int; i++){
     if (i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Hoppity \n");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        printf("Hophop \n");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Hop \n");
    }   
}
```

As you can see, the last conditional doesn't quite work. What type of control construct should I use? else?

Thanks alot.

Comment: What do you mean "as you can see?" You showed code, but no output. The last `if` statement looks okay from here.

Comment: `if` does not form a loop. A loop is a *closed* thing where start and end meet at some point. Draw a sequence diagram, and you'll see. BTW, draw a sequence diagram for this code, too.

Comment: @DanFego I need that If statement to override the other two if statements when it is true, so only "Hop" is printed, instead of 

"Hoppity"
"HopHop"
"Hop"

Comment: This is called "The fizz-buzz test" and is used as a basic screening in an interview to see if you know how to program at all. Unfortunately you're failing; you need to look up what `else` does in basic programming. It's also worth mentioning that `if` is not a loop, it's a conditional whose block gets executed at most once.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm in High School. :-) Freshman.

Comment: Ah, the power of "else".

Comment: @Number7even - excellent - by the time you do your first interview, this won't be a daunting problem :) You'd be amazed at how many people with Masters in CS I've interviewed have failed this.

Comment: Cool.
Thanks for the help all.

Comment: This is the FizzBuzz problem: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html

Comment: Maybe yall could plus 1 my question. XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; i <= file_int; i++){
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Five and three\n");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Three\n");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        printf("Five\n");
    } else {
        printf("None of the conditions passed\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Number7even If you find the above answer as a correct one, please confirm so by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `else-ifs` and make us of the fact that

`(i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) <=> (i % 15 == 0)`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= file_int; i++){
  if (i % 15 == 0)
    printf("Hop \n");
  else if (i % 3 == 0)
    printf("Hoppity \n");
  else if (i % 5 == 0)
    printf("Hophop \n"); 
}
```

Of course you can also get away without using any control structures except the `for`-loop at all:

```
const char* values[15] = {"Hop \n", "", "", "Hoppity \n", "", 
                          "Hophop \n", "Hoppity \n", "", "", "Hoppity \n", 
                          "Hophop \n", "", "Hoppity \n", "", ""};
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
  printf(values[i % 15]);
```

That solution is slightly insane for this example, but it shows how you can do things differently (and it's not so farfetched when writing code where you shall never ever have more then a certain number of branch paths in one function (overzealous coding conventions...)).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, keeping closer to your original code.  Although the `else` solution is indeed more efficient (and elegant).

```
for (i = 1; i <= file_int; i++){
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
        printf("Hoppity \n");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 != 0) {
        printf("Hophop \n");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Hop \n");
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Dave: I would not really call that *elegant*, to me it is harder to read and parse by a human than the *if-else* equivalent (i.e. you need to check all the conditions against the rest to *know* that they are exclusive, that is no two messages will be printed)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas He said `else` was more powerful. I'm saying `else` is more elegant

Comment: I agree the `else` method is more elegant, though my intent was to point out that it is more efficient (for which powerful was the wrong word).  Edited.

Comment: @Dave: Sorry, I misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it, and not recommending it, as it can be harder to read as it abuses conversions from `bool` to `int`:

```
int msg = (i % 3 == 0) + 2*(i % 5 == 0);
switch ( msg ) {
case 3:
   cout << "Multiple of 3 and 5";
case 2: 
   cout << "Multiple of 5";
case 1:
   cout << "Multiple of 3";
}
```

which can be further condensed into:

```
const char* msgs[] = { "", "Multiple 3", "Multiple 5", "Multiple 3 and 5" };
cout << msgs[ (i%3==0) + 2*(i%5==0) ];
```

Of course, both solutions are against the question itself, as they are not *if* constructs, but rather avoid the use of *if* in the first case, and *branches* in general in the second case.